# getting all rows where complex condition holds in scipy/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

what is the simplest way to get all rows where a complex condition holds for an `ndarray` that represents a 2d matrix? e.g. get all rows where all the values are above 5 or all the values are below 5?

thanks.

Comment: You should probably select an (and a few other) answer(s), or comment on the existing answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably know that boolean arrays can be used for indexing, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
x2 = x[x<5]
```

For a boolean array, `np.all` lets you apply it across a given axis:

```
y = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

b = y < 6
b1 = np.all(b, axis=0)
b2 = np.all(b, axis=1)

y1 = y[b1]
y2 = y[b2]
```

It only returns the arrays which meet the criteria, so the shape is not preserved. (If you do need to preserve the shape, then take a look at masked arrays.)

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the row indices of the rows where all values are lower or higher than 5:

```
x = numpy.arange(100).reshape(20,5)
numpy.where((x > 5).all(axis=1) ^ (x < 5).all(axis=1))
```

or more concisely (but not proceeding via the same logic):

```
numpy.where(((x > 5) ^ (x < 5)).all(axis=1))
```

To fetch the data, rather than the indices, use the boolean result directly:

```
x[((x > 5) ^ (x < 5)).all(axis=1)]
```